# Docker swarm recreate containers after reboot node

Tags: docker, containers, swarm

Docker swarm recreate containers after reboot node. That is, it actually destroys old containers and launches new ones. 
I do not like this behavior. How to change it?

Comment: What is the comportment you would like? Restarting the old container and not starting a new one? Swarm will not do that because when a node go down, the container will be rescheduled on other nodes when not in global mode.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behavior of Swarm Mode and I'm not aware of an option to change the behavior that doesn't also risk worse issues (starting too many containers, and orphaned containers running outside of Swarm Mode's control). Containers should be treated as ephemeral, without persistent data inside the container (that data should be in volumes).